# SQL using 0 row from where as 0 rows to group by instead of nothing

Tags: sql, group-by, count

This is my table

[image]

I am using the next query

```
    SELECT XFailTbl.id, 
       xfail, 
       yfail 
FROM   (SELECT Count(*) AS XFail, 
               [id] 
        FROM   [table] 
        WHERE  ( x < xmin 
                  OR x > xmax ) 
        GROUP  BY [id]) AS XFailTbl 
       JOIN (SELECT Count(*) AS YFail, 
                    [id] 
             FROM   [table] 
             WHERE  ( y < ymin 
                       OR y > ymax ) 
             GROUP  BY [id]) AS YFailTbl 
         ON XFailTbl.id = YFailTbl.id
```

I got the next result

[image]

my expecting result is

[image]

I understand that I cant using the condition of  `(Y<Ymin OR Y>YMax)` because I get 0 rows to the group by and it can't count the 0 rows because it doesn't know it exists 
But what is the way to get the expecting result?  I have no idea...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when X < Xmin or X > XMax then 1 else 0 end) as xfail,
       sum(case when Y < Ymin or Y > YMax then 1 else 0 end) as yfail
from
group by id;
```